# Question about Clifford volume element

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, spin-geometry

I'm a little confused with the following:

Let $M$ be a $m$ dimensional Riemannian manifold and $e_1,\cdots,e_m$ be a local orthonormal base of $TM$. Let
$$
\omega_\mathbb{R}=c(e_1)\cdots c(e_m)
$$
where $c(\cdot)$ is the Clifford multiplication.

**Firstly, my question is why $\omega_{\mathbb{R}}$ is an element of ${\rm End}(\Lambda^*TM)$ but not an element of $Cl(TM)$?**

Additionally, if we consider the real Dirac operator
$$ D_\mathbb{R}:=\sum_{i=1}^m \omega_\mathbb{R}c(e_i)\nabla_{e_i}$$
**why does $\omega_\mathbb{R}c(e_i)\in Cl^{\rm even}(TM)$
for all $i$ and $D_\mathbb{R}$ acts on $\Omega^{\rm even}(M)$?**

I'm not sure if the question is too easy on MO. Could you please give me some help with the details? Thanks in advance.

Comment: As written, your $\omega_{\mathbb{R}}$ *is* a global section of the real Clifford bundle of $TM$. However, depending on your choice of conventions, normalising $\omega_{\mathbb{R}}$ to satisfy $\omega_{\mathbb{R}}^2 = 1$ requires rescaling by a suitable power of $\mathrm{i}$, and *this* now gives you a global section of the endomorphism bundle of $TM$ that doesn’t come from a global section of the real Clifford bundle of $TM$.

Comment: Also, are you familiar with the notion of *Clifford action* or *Clifford module*? You need to know how sections of the Clifford bundle induce sections of the endomorphism bundle in a manner compatible with the Clifford relations.

Comment: $\omega_\mathbb{R}\in {\rm End}(\Lambda^* TM)$? I can just see that $\omega_\mathbb{R}\in Cl(TM)$ . Could you please give me more details? Thanks@BranimirĆaćić

Comment: This should all be in whatever textbook you’re referring to (Lawson–Michelson, Berline-Getzler-Vegne, etc.). What is your main reference?

Comment: I'm reading S.Goette's paper at the link https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0010199.pdf, I got stuck in the proof of Proposition 2.9. Could you tell me the page number of the references which you told me about?

Comment: You’re going to have a hard time reading a paper like this without at least skimming an introduction to Clifford modules and Dirac operators. Goette and Semmelmann cite the book of Lawson and Michelson and use compatible notation and conventions (at least as far as I can tell), so I strongly recommend you take a look through the introductory sections of that book. Alternatively, since Lawson and Michelson is quite a tough book for beginners, you may wish to look instead at Friedrich’s *Dirac operators in Riemannian geometry* for the relevant basic concepts in compatible notation.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you are stuck at the proof of Theorem 2.7? $\omega_{\mathbb R}$ is an element of the real Clifford algebra, but we need its action on $\Lambda^\bullet T^*M$ here. And for the second question, since $M$ is odd-dimensional, we can use $\omega_{\mathbb R}$ to reduce to a Dirac operator that acts on even forms instead of swapping even and odd forms. If you like, you can also send further questions by email. Let me also note that there is a mistake in that paper that is corrected in https://arxiv.org/abs/0709.4586 Example 2.3.